# Tried every option I can find, still can't make files not 'read-only' after windows 10 update

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, windows-explorer, read-only

Recently update a computer to windows 10 and started getting an error from a program (solidworks) that boiled down to not having the permissions needed for a folder.

Issue is even if I open properties and uncheck read only it's checked again if I look again.

I've tried moving the folder to a different location on the computer, issue still stands.

I'm logged in as Admin, gone through properties, security, etc and ensured I have Full control for everything to do with it.

Tried 'attrib -r +s C:\drive' in cmd run as admin, no change.

I've been trying every option I can find, anyone have any other ideas or thoughts?

Comment: The exact error you receive would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, good point. trying to change anything gives "This forder is read only" and working is solidworks  gives "You need to have administrator privileges co complete this" or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the **read-only** checkbox in the folder's **Properties** dialog. It's not a status indicator, it's a tri-state switch. There will always be a gray square when the dialog is displayed for any folder:
[image]

Have you turned off **Controlled Folder Access**? Click on Start & type "controlled" and you should be offered the option:
[image]

[image]

Comment: we are using trend micro for our security so windows defender is turned off and controlled folder access can't be accessed. I'm thinking it may be the security software that's causing the issue then?

Comment: It may be. I have no working knowledge of 3rd-part securtity software.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the cause, still haven't found a solution